# Skype4Py User leave event

Tags: skype4py

Is there an event that is called when a user leaves a chat group, providing the username?

I've searched in the events list, but I couldn't find it, maybe I missed it.
Or can I check it through a OnMessageStatus event, and that it has a special leaving enum?

Answer (score 0):

This may work. I'm not sure if it will change only at the end of the call or while users change.

```
def OnCall(call, status):
    global CallStatus
    CallStatus = status
    print 'Call status: ' + CallStatusText(status) + f.handle
```

so on the call Status while it's changing it will update with usernames.